# Special integral, Help me solve it please!

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, gamma-function, complex-integration

1. When solving a problem i met an integral that:
   $$\int_0^\infty ln(x)x^ae^{-x}dx$$
   Where a is a complex number with a negative real part. Any ideas for solving it?
2. And other one is:
   $$\int_0^\infty x^ae^{-x}dx$$
   I tried to use gamma function to solve it, however the result is $\Gamma(a)$ and a, as I mentioned is a complex number with neagative real part so any ideas to expansion it? I need some approximation for it or some series then I can try to cut that off.

Comment: If  real part of $a\le -1$, the integral diverges at $x=0$.

Comment: Can you give me a reference for that comment?

Comment: don't have a reference - just try it.